# Error after importing OpenCV Library for Android into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm struggling with an error after importing the OpenCV library in Eclipse. I think I did what I should but maybe I missed something. There is no error with the samples but with my application there is and also with the OpenCV Library-2.4.10.

Here is what I have as an output:

**Problems**

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.  Cammect     line 209, external location: /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/add-application.mk  C/C++ Problem
make: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.  OpenCV Library - 2.4.10     line 209, external location: /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/add-application.mk  C/C++ Problem
make: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.  src     line 209, external location: /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/add-application.mk  C/C++ Problem
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.    RemoteSystemsTempFiles          C/C++ Problem
```

**Console:**

```
22:21:19 **** Clean-only build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Library - 2.4.10 ****
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build clean 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk    
/home/crash-id/Development/SDK/android-ndk-r10c/build/core/add-application.mk:209: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.

22:21:19 Build Finished (took 132ms)
```

**ErrorLog:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.core
Error
Sun Feb 08 22:21:23 EET 2015
Invalid ZIP archive: /home/crash-id/Development/SDK/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/bin/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.cdt.core
Error
Sun Feb 08 21:45:35 EET 2015
Error: Cannot run program "/ndk-build": Unknown reason

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/ndk-build": Unknown reason
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.Spawner.exec(Spawner.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.Spawner.<init>(Spawner.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.ProcessFactory.exec(ProcessFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.CommandLauncher.execute(CommandLauncher.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.BuildRunnerHelper.build(BuildRunnerHelper.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ExternalBuildRunner.invokeExternalBuild(ExternalBuildRunner.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ExternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(ExternalBuildRunner.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.cdt.core
Error
Sun Feb 08 21:45:35 EET 2015
Error: Cannot run program "/ndk-build": Unknown reason

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/ndk-build": Unknown reason
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.Spawner.exec(Spawner.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.Spawner.<init>(Spawner.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.utils.spawner.ProcessFactory.exec(ProcessFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.CommandLauncher.execute(CommandLauncher.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.BuildRunnerHelper.build(BuildRunnerHelper.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ExternalBuildRunner.invokeExternalBuild(ExternalBuildRunner.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ExternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(ExternalBuildRunner.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

[image]

Comment: NDK build needs to be used only if **your application** have JNI part. Other wise you can smply copy OpenCV libs. Please follow steps here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization

Comment: I will have jni part. Okay, that's the problem with my app, but why do I get error with the OpenCV Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I changed to OpenCV Library 2.4.9 instead of 2.4.10, errors disappeared. And the error with my app disappeared after I created a jni folder with the .mk files.

Answer (score 0):

From your error logs, it seems that the path to your Android NDK is wrong. You can correct this by specifying the full path to your Android NDK `ndk-build` in Eclipse.

First, create a `Build Variable`. In Eclipse, go to `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Build` -> `Build Variables`. Add a new variable (you could name it `NDK_ROOT` or whatever you want) that references the full path of your Android NDK `ndk-build` file.

Then, click `Apply` and click on `Environment` (`Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `Build` -> `Environment`) and add the variable you just created. Click `Apply` and `OK`.

After that, right-click on your Open-CV-Library, and select `Properties`. Navigate to `C/C++ Build` -> `Environment` and add the newly created variable there as well. Click `Apply` and `OK`.

That should work. That's how I fixed mine.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

Another fix may be to use version 2.4.9 instead of version 2.4.10, since the current instructions on the OpenCV website are for version 2.4.9.

Comment: @Crash-ID Okay. Another fix may be to use version 2.4.9 instead of version 2.4.10, since the instructions on the OpenCV website are for version 2.4.9.

Comment: Okay, thank you :) I'll try it tomorrow, cuz it's late here right now.

Comment: After I changed to 2.4.9 I had no errors. And the error with my app disappeared after I created a jni folder with the .mk files. Thank you.